# Contract call: data out of bounds

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, javascript, error, aave

I'm working on a nextjs/react project in which i want to fetch the health factor of an address on AAVE. This can be done by calling `getUserAcountData(address)` on the lending pool contract. I can sucessfully call it in a simple nodejs project but when i call it in my nextjs/react app it gives me an error.

Here is the code I run (on ropsten testnet). `LP_ABI` is simply the ABI for the AAVE Lending Pool Contract which can be found [here](https://github.com/aave/aave-protocol/blob/master/contracts/lendingpool/LendingPool.sol).

All addresses are Ropsten addresses

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import setupWeb3 from '../src/web3'
import LP_ABI from '../abi/LendingPool.json'

class Index extends Component {
  web3 = null

  getHealthFactor = async () => {
    let lpContract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(
      LP_ABI,
      "0x9E5C7835E4b13368fd628196C4f1c6cEc89673Fa"
    )
    try {
      await lpContract.methods
        .getUserAccountData("0x8e5687908487cf9362632D074965Fe4B83D660a2")
        .call()
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Contract', error)
    }
 }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const web3Manager = await setupWeb3()
    this.web3 = web3Manager.web3
  }
}
```

the `setupWeb3` function

```js
// ´../src/web3.js´-file
const Web3 = require('web3')
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider')

async function setupWeb3() {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const walletProvider = new HDWalletProvider(
        <MNEMONIC>,
        <INFURA HTTP ENDPOINT>
      )
      var web3 = new Web3(walletProvider)
      return { web3: web3 }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('web3.js', error)
      return { web3: null }
    }
  }
}
export default setupWeb3
```

the error

```js
Contract Error: data out-of-bounds (length=132, offset=160, code=BUFFER_OVERRUN, version=abi/5.0.0-beta.153)
    at Logger.makeError (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib.esm/index.js:166)
    at Logger.throwError (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib.esm/index.js:175)
    at Reader._peekBytes (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/abstract-coder.js:112)
    at Reader.readBytes (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/abstract-coder.js:123)
    at Reader.readValue (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/abstract-coder.js:129)
    at NumberCoder.decode (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/number.js:32)
    at :3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/array.js:78
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at unpack (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/array.js:56)
    at TupleCoder.decode (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/tuple.js:22)
    at AbiCoder.decode (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/abi-coder.js:88)
    at ABICoder._N_E.push../node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js.ABICoder.decodeParameters (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js:347)
    at Contract._N_E.push../node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js.Contract._decodeMethodReturn (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:572)
    at Method.outputFormatter (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:935)
    at Method._N_E.push../node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js.Method.formatOutput (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:169)
    at sendTxCallback (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:653)
    at onJsonrpcResult (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:179)
    at :3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/@trufflesuite/web3-provider-engine/index.js:240
    at :3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/async/internal/once.js:12
    at replenish (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:61)
    at :3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:71
    at eachLimit (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/async/eachLimit.js:43)
    at :3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/async/internal/doLimit.js:9
    at end (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/@trufflesuite/web3-provider-engine/index.js:217)
    at Object.callback (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/@trufflesuite/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js:72)
    at cbOnce (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/xhr/index.js:64)
    at XMLHttpRequest.loadFunc (:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/webpack:/_N_E/node_modules/xhr/index.js:131)
```

Comment: Please get rid of all those `sessionStorage.getItem(...)` expressions, and place the actual values that they return instead. We're not supposed to guess what this function does!

Comment: Please also bother to specify what `LP_ABI` is, because we're not supposed to guess that either!

Comment: You may well get rid of all the frontend-related (HTML) code here, because it has absolutely no relevance to the problem that you're describing.

Comment: Note that a question here should ideally enclose ALL the relevant information and ONLY the relevant information.

Comment: I agree the front end was unnessesary, the other things i thought were pretty self-explanatory but i have updated the question as per your comments!

Comment: What is "the Lending Pool Contract"? This is not a part of the Ethereum standard, so readers here aren't supposed to know what it is.

Comment: @goodvibration The Lending Pool Contract is an AAVE contract. AAVE is already mentioned in the question. However, if you feel that this needs clarification I can add it!

Comment: So you just invented a tag named `aave`? This is not standard Ethereum facts that everybody knows. It is required information, so please share the relevant code.

Comment: @goodvibration Yeah since this pertained to the AAVE protocol I thought it would be appropriate to also tag this question with aave. Perhaps I am mistaken in how the tags should be used? Good suggestion! I added a link to the AAVE github pointing to LendingPool.sol file!

Comment: And `0x9E5C7835E4b13368fd628196C4f1c6cEc89673Fa ` is supposed to be the address of that contract? Because I'm watching it on etherscan, and it's just an externally-owned account, i.e., not even a contract (let alone, not **this** contract)!

Comment: @goodvibration Yes it is the address of the contract. Did you check the ropsten etherscan? https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x9e5c7835e4b13368fd628196c4f1c6cec89673fa I notice now that i must've removed the mentioning of ropsten from the question somewhere along my edits.

Comment: No, you did not say anything about ropsten. Again - too much guess-work is required in order to address your question!

Comment: @goodvibration oh actually as per the 4th edit i stated that i ran the code on ropsten testnet which was the same point at which i added the aave tag.

Comment: Well, there were so many missing details AND redundant details at that point, that the actual network wasn't even something that I needed to focus on. As I commented here earlier on, a question should ideally enclose ALL the relevant information and ONLY the relevant information.

Comment: @goodvibration I agree that the was information missing and some unnecessary information. However, I feel that this has now been addressed and corrected such that anyone interested in addressing this question should hopefully have a good starting point.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Please I need help.